# Node.js websocket npm ws module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket

I am trying to build a chat app. In the first step the user sends username and if the name is not already existing is logged in. Then can send a message to another user, here comes the error, after the first messages the server sends to the other clients (except the one the message came from) this message but it gets duplicated and the more messages I send the number of duplicates seems to multiply.
I tried so much changes, including sending back the message from server to all client including the one it originated from, but cannot find a solution for these duplicates --- please help me!
(built with bootstrap & jQuery)

Tried sending a message from user to server, UI shows the message to user and server sends message to all other connected users except the one it came from, all other users should see the message too then on their UI

Here is the HTML & CSS UI:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <style>
.formular {
    width: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    }

li {list-style: none;}

#header {position: fixed;
top: 0}

#msgDisplay {padding-top: 2em;}
</style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container" id="header">
       WEBSOCKETS
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-3" id="msgDisplay">
        <ul class="messages">

        </ul>
        <form action="?" class="formular">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="input">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="app.js">

</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the user JavaScript:

```
let scrollBottom = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 999999);
    let heightForm = document.querySelector('.formular').offsetHeight;
    document.querySelector('.messages').style.paddingBottom = heightForm + 'px';
};

let showMessage = (msg) => {
    console.log('MSG DISPLAY: ', msg)

    $('.messages').append($('<li>').html(msg))
    scrollBottom()
}


let sendmessageF = () => {
    ws.send($('#input').val());
    $('.input').val(''); // Eingabe leeren
}


window.onresize = scrollBottom;

let username = '';
let ws;
let wsOK = false;

let submitF = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (username == '') {
        username = $('.input').val();

        if (wsOK == false) {
            // Create WebSocket connection.
            ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5041');
            ws.binaryType = 'blob';

            // Connection opened
            ws.addEventListener('open', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                console.log('NEW SOCKED OPENED', e)
                console.log('NEW USER: ', username)
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ req: '/login', user: username }))
                wsOK = true;
            });
            }
    }
    else if (username != ''){
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ req: '/message', message: $('.input').val() }))
        showMessage($('.input').val())
    }


 // Listen for messages
 ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log('Message from server => ', event.data);
    
    if (event.data instanceof Blob) {

        let reader = new FileReader(); // UM BLOB AUSZULESEN
        reader.readAsText(event.data)
        reader.onload = () => {
            console.log("Result BLOB: " + reader.result);
            showMessage('BLOB: ', reader.result)
        };
    }
    else if (JSON.parse(event.data) instanceof Object){
        let msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('SERVER MSG: ', msg)

        if(msg.itype == 'loginSuccess'){
            showMessage(msg.res)
            $('.btn').html('Senden')
            username = msg.res.split(':')[1].trim()
            console.log('USERNAME: ', username)
            }
        else if (msg.itype == 'loginFail'){
            showMessage(msg.res)
            username = '';
            wsOK = false;
            ws.destroy()
        }
        else if (msg.itype == 'valUserMsg'){
            console.log('HIER ???')
            showMessage(msg.res)
        }
    }
});

}
```

$('.btn').click(submitF)`

Here is the node.js Server:

```
    const express = require('express'); // NPM INSTALLEREN
    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5041;
    const server = require('http').createServer(app)

const fs = require('fs');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // NPM INSTALLEREN

const WebSocket = require('ws') // NPM INSTALLEREN
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: server })

// const Random = require('./modules/random.js');

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('SERVER PORT: ', PORT)
})
app.use(express.static('www'));
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/xml' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' }));


let wsConns = [];
let allUser = [];

wss.on('connection', (wsConn) => { // wsConn ORIGIN
    console.log('NEUER CLIENT CONNECTED')
    let username = '';
        
    wsConn.on('message', (message) => {
        let msgReceived = JSON.parse(message)
        console.log('MESSAGE RECEIVED: ', msgReceived)
                
        if (msgReceived.req == '/login') {
           
            username = msgReceived.user
            if (allUser.indexOf(username) == -1) {
                allUser.push(username)
                wsConns.push(wsConn)
                console.log('ALLUSER: ',allUser)
                console.log('WSCONNS: ',wsConns.length)
                wsConn.send(JSON.stringify({itype:'loginSuccess',res:`Username akzeptiert: ${username}`}))
            }
            else {
                wsConn.send(JSON.stringify({itype:'loginFail',res:'Username schon vergeben!'}))
            }
        }
        else if (msgReceived.req == '/message'){
            console.log('HIER???')
            wss.clients.forEach((client)=>{ // anstatt wss.clients würde auch wsConns gehen (Arr mit allen Conn)
                if(client !== wsConn && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN){
                    client.send(JSON.stringify({itype:'valUserMsg',res:                                                                msgReceived.message }))
                }
            })
            console.log('WSCONNS: ',wsConns.length)
        }
        

       
    })

    })
```

Comment: Another thing I need to mention, maybe this helps someone understand my problem here, I tried another version and still got the same result. The messages from the user who is logged in 1st get to all other users 1x, the messages from user 2nd logged in get to all users 2x, the messages from user who is logged in 3rd come to all other users 3x. It has something to do with the ws connections or the server but cannot figure out what...

Answer (score 0):

use `ws.onmessage = ()...` instead of `ws.addEventListener('message', ...`